# Create multiple start menu and program group entries - either for single user or all users

Tags: install4j

My installer has a "create program group" action which initially asks user whether to create start menu entries only for current user or for all users.  Installer further creates multiple program group (using "create program group") and start menu (using "create start menu entry").

Each of these groups has this setting - "create for all users".
I would like to know the way such that all the program groups and start menu entries can be controlled using a central flag - such that they are created for all users or for only current user.

One hacky way is to use create two sets of entries for both - one with "create for all users" flag on and other is off. Then use a conditional expression and read the value of system variable "sys.programGroupAllUsers ".

Is there a better way, would like to create only one set of entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out by running a script which sets the value using install4j api.
It is not possible to do via install4j IDE

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

If the "Create program group" **screen** is present in the installer and if it is shown, the screen will set the installer variable `sys.programGroupAllUsers`. If the screen is not shown, the installer variable will not be set.

If this installer variable is set, it overrides the "Create for all users" property of all "Create program group" **actions** (but not of the "Create start menu entry" actions).